# How can I find out which Stack Exchange site is appropriate for my type of question?

Tags: discussion

I already know, that META Academia is not the perfect place to start, but my original question which I did not post yet is related to academia - to the specific research I need to make. The Academia is about the process of making the research, not the research content itself.

I would consider this question thus to be about the process of the research, because I am not asking about the research itself, but the process - *looking for a way to continue the research* Thus Meta Academia (asking about asking about research) seems to be at least partially appropriate place to ask.

So background to the question: I have a research in which I need to find a big amount of textual data, which have some type of content. In my case, I am looking for texts, that are written in aggressive way, to process it later. I am having severe difficulties looking for such content and I believe there must be an appropriate stack exchange website to ask for a suggestion on how to look for such content, or - directly - where such content can be found.

Question being - how can I find out which stack exchange website is appropriate to post such a problem? It is related to computer science since the texts will be algorithimically processed. It is related to linguistics, because the type of processing and purpose is natural language processing. It is related to Academia in the sense that I am looking for some research material and I do not know how to look for it efficiently... But none of it is quite a good fit.

Is it likely, that there is no such stackexchange page, that would fit this type of question? Should I just pick one and hope for not getting downvotes?

Comment: I just looked around for you. I found a question [Where can I find free spatio-temporal dataset for download?](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/997/10960) on Data Science SE, which is similar to what you want to ask. You may want to post this question on their meta to see if they are the right place.

Comment: Thank you very much, I read through the names of sites but I must have (dis)missed that accidentally. Feel free to post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked around for you. I found a question

[Where can I find free spatio-temporal dataset for download?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/997/10960) on Data Science SE,

which is similar to what you want to ask. You may want to post this question on their meta to see if they are the right place.

Comment: Are you saying that when in doubt, one could ask on the corresponding Meta, Is this the right place for such-and-so question?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is not a stack exchange site for every question. If you cannot find an appropriate site, you can always propose a new site on Area51. It is a long process, but it is an option,

Second, you are correct that it does not seem like a good question for us. Looking through the [list of all SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name) it looks like cogsci, data, linguistics, open data, and philosophy might provide a reasonable fit, depending on the specifics. You should take a look at their help centers and if you have questions about scope ask in their meta or chat.